# Unable to set dynamic input fields ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to ionic,

I want to set dynamic input fields to my form,
Here is my code but i am unable to set

**home.ts**

```
constructor() {
  pData = //Got data from server;
  this.myForm1 = this._fb.group({
    ship_owner_name: [pData.ship_owner_name],
    deck_array: this._fb.array([])
  });
  this.AddItemData(pData.deck_array);
}

AddItemData(item) {
  const arrayControl = < FormArray > this.myForm1.controls['deck_array'];
  let newGroup = this._fb.group({
    selectedDeck: item
  });
  arrayControl.push(newGroup);
}
```

Server data i have retrived is:

```
pData = {
  "ship_owner_name": "john smith",
  "deck_array": [
    "MD 1",
    "MD 2"
  ],
}
```

Code for template
**home.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm1">
    <ion-list no-lines class="listMargin">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="labelColor" stacked>
            Ship owner name 
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="ship_owner_name" type="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    <div formArrayName="deck_array" style="background-color:white">
        <ion-list *ngFor="let obj of myForm1.controls.deck_array.controls;let i=index">

            <div [formGroupName]="i" >
                    <ion-item no-lines>
                    <ion-input placeholder="select from list or type in"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

            </div>

        </ion-list>

</div>

</ion-list>
```

***Please help and thanks in advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your implementation.

For starters, you're making `deck_array` in the form a `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s when it should be a `FormArray` of `FormControl`s

Secondly, you're not going to get the reference of `desk_array` like this: `<FormArray>this.myForm1.controls['deck_array'];`

Thirdly, I'm not really sure where you're getting the `_fb` from if you haven't injected it in your `constructor`.

Fourth, you should be making your `constructor` as lean as possible. So all the code to get the data from the server, instantiate the form, and set it's value should go inside `ngOnInit`.

Fifth, you should be creating a getter in your typescript class that is going to give you the `FormArray`'s `controls`. Also, you should be using `[formControlName]` instead of the `[formGroupName]` directive to bind the form to the view.

I've fixed all these issues on the form and now it works as expected. Here's what I did.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  pData;
  myForm1;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Suppose that this is obtained by an AJAX Call to the server.
    this.pData = {
      "ship_owner_name": "john smith",
      "deck_array": [
        "MD 1",
        "MD 2"
      ],
    };

    this.myForm1 = this._fb.group({
      ship_owner_name: [this.pData.ship_owner_name],
      deck_array: this._fb.array([])
    });
    this.AddItemData(this.pData.deck_array);
    console.log(this.myForm1.value);
  }

  AddItemData(item) {
    const arrayControl = (<FormArray>this.myForm1.get('deck_array'));
    console.log(this.pData.deck_array);
    const controls = this.pData.deck_array.map(value => this._fb.control(value));
    console.log(controls);
    controls.forEach(control => arrayControl.push(control));
  }

  get controlsArray() {
    return (<FormArray>this.myForm1.get('deck_array')).controls;
  }

}
```

And then in your template, change:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let obj of myForm1.controls.deck_array.controls;let i=index">
```

to

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let obj of controlsArray;let i=index">
```

Here's the full template as you've given:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm1">
  <ion-list no-lines class="listMargin">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label class="labelColor" stacked>
        Ship owner name
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="ship_owner_name" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div formArrayName="deck_array" style="background-color:white">
      <ion-list *ngFor="let obj of controlsArray;let i=index">
        <div>
          <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-input 
              [formControlName]="i"
              placeholder="select from list or type in"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

Here's a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-binding-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your reference.

Comment: That's probably coz your `this.pData` is not obtained yet. Make sure your `this.pData` is obtained from the server and then only you should try creating the form.

Or you can create the form and get the data from AJAX calls parallelly and then call `setValue` or `patchValue` on the form.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: You shouldn't be using formGroup since it is a formControl. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179243/discussion-between-apple-developer-and-siddharth-ajmera).

Comment: inside  'AddItemData(){ const arrayControl = (<FormArray>this.myForm1.get('deck_array'));
      
      const controls = item.map(value => 
        arrayControl.push(value)
  
      ); '  why i cant push with values directly?